# What do you call the directions orthogonal to uptown/downtown in Manhattan?

Tags: american-english, phrase-requests

While in many places, the notions of "uptown" and "downtown" can be somewhat fuzzy and vague, in Manhattan, these two words have clear definitions - if you are standing on *n*<sup>th</sup> Street, then uptown is in the direction of *n+1*<sup>th</sup> Street, while downtown is in the direction of *n-1*<sup>th</sup> Street.

What do you call the directions *orthogonal* to that? That is, if you are standing on 8<sup>th</sup> Avenue, what do you call the direction you travel to get to 7<sup>th</sup> Avenue or 9<sup>th</sup> Avenue? (In particular, what do people who actually live in New York call these directions? It's not difficult to come up with reasonably clear ways of expressing these directions [see below], but I want to know what natives call it.)

---

Possible options (but I have no idea which of these, if any, are actually used by New York natives):

- Just **east** / **west** (since Manhattan is sort-of-but-not-really oriented to the compass directions)
- **towards the Hudson River** / **towards the East River** (but does anybody actually say this? Seems unlikely.)
- something based on roads that run along the Manhattan coast, like **towards the FDR** / **towards Henry Hudson Parkway** (but again, does anybody say this? Doubt it.)

Comment: You can take the crosstown bus If it's raining or it's cold. That'll get you to the east side or the west side, or even the zoo.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger The animals will love it if you do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The orthogonal travel to *uptown/downtown* in Manhattan is **crosstown**.

Yes, I know that *u/d* is binary and *crosstown* is not. New Yorkers ususally know where they presently are. If they are West of Fifth Avenue and say they are going *crosstown*, they are going East. Ditto on East of Fifth.

When current location cannot serve as the indicator or more precision is sought, a New Yorker would probably say *to the East Side* or *to the West Side*. If you were on the West Side (say 9th Avenue) and were only going a few blocks east, (say to 7th), you might say *go east to 7th.* Probably the direction would not be mentioned, except to a non-native, since NYers know !st is east and 12th is west.

Perhaps more commonly, New Yorkers talk about the neighborhoods to which they are heading, rather than the direction itself. For example, in Manhattan alone we have

> - the East Village
> - the West Village
> - SoHo
> - NoHo
> - Tribeca
> - Midtown (sometimes Midtown East or Midtown West)
> - the Upper West Side
> - the Upper Upper West side
> - the Upper East Side
> - Turtle Bay
> - Chinatown
> - Little Italy
> - Harlem
> - East Harlem
> - Morningside Heights
> - Riverside
> - Yorkville
> - Sutton Place
> - Chelsea
> - the Flatiron District
> - the Garment District
> - the Theater District
> - Battery Park
> - Wall Street
> - South Ferry
> - [and many, many more]

Comment: It’s funny: outside of maps and such, you normally think of the up–down opposition in terms of the z-axis, unless perhaps you’ve gone hyperbolic and so it’s longitudinal as with maps. Not sure we have anything for latitudinal travel.

Comment: @tchrist It is further complicated in cities where *downtown* means the central business district regardless of its compass orientation from the speaker. That is not the case in Manhattan. When you say *downtown* you mean *south* (roughly).

Comment: Here people speak (rather oxymoronically, if you think about it) of “going up to Nederland” or “down to Boulder”, but that is z-axis talk, because we differ in elevation by almost 4 kilofeet.  It’s actually an east–west relationship between the two burgs but everyone uses up–down because the altitude change is much more important here.

Comment: @tchrist Your misspeaking is probably a function of a *Rocky Mountain high*.

Comment: Evocative list. But, by staying within Manhattan, you missed out my favourite. Sorry, favorite: **Dumbo**.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That crossed my mind as a fascinating neighborhood name, but introducing Brooklyn add myriads, and the complication that Brooklyn *downtown* has nothing to do with direction. And then you have to explain that it is a location description not an elephant memorial.

Comment: Yes. We'll cross that bridge when we come to it.

Comment: It’s not misspeaking. It’s just that when you live in an area where you have to take miles of altitude into account, that sometimes makes more difference than north–south orientation.  I promise that if you talk to people standing atop any of the Front Range’s three fourteeners — Mt Evans, Pike’s Peak, or Long’s Peak — gazing down at Denver almost two miles below them, that *down* is the only appropriate direction to speak of when getting to Denver from there. Changes of altitude trump those of latitude.